# Menu command resetting xla menu

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel code that creates buttons on the menu command, this works perfectly, however, I now want to include an XLA button but when I load the xla it never works, now when I remove the menu command code, the xla works. I think it is a result of the .reset function which is resetting the menu and calling a function that does not include the xla command. So I guess the question is how do I call an xla function from a sub in a macro.

```
Private Sub createMenu()
'define the variables
    Dim mnuDownload1 As Menu
    Dim mnuDownload2 As Menu
    Dim mnuDownload3 As Menu
    Dim mnuDownload4 As Menu

    'create the menue bar
    With MenuBars(xlWorksheet)
        .Reset
        .Menus.Add "Import", 1
        .Menus.Add "RAR", 1
        .Menus.Add "Admin", 1
        .Menus.Add "Install XLA", 1

        'define the menue bar
        Set mnuDownload1 = MenuBars(xlWorksheet).Menus("Import")
        Set mnuDownload2 = MenuBars(xlWorksheet).Menus("RAR")
        Set mnuDownload3 = MenuBars(xlWorksheet).Menus("Admin")
        Set mnuDownload4 = MenuBars(xlWorksheet).Menus("Install XLA")

        'for each defined menu bar at the sub item , the first "" is the name of the item. The second "" is the macro name
        With mnuDownload1.MenuItems
         .Add "Settings", "inputform_open"
         .Add "Import", "RAR_Import"
        End With
        With mnuDownload2.MenuItems
         .Add "RAR", "RAR"
        End With
        With mnuDownload3.MenuItems
         .Add "Admin", "pass_open"
        End With
        With mnuDownload4.MenuItems
         .Add "If the XLA is not available press here", "InstallAddIn"
        End With
End With
End Sub
```

This runs when the book is open, etc. So I think the .reset is making the XLA addin disappear.

Comment: Wow - `MenuBars`! How old is this code?? Anyway, if you're trying to call a routine in another workbook, you should really include its name in the `OnAction`  parameter: `"'addin name.xla'!InstallAddIn` for example.

Comment: Stop, we're pretty backward. What other method would you recommend?So basically .Add "If the XLA is not available press here", "'addin name.xla'!InstallAddIn". I did get it to work by putting Application.AddIns("XLAADDIN").Installed = False, Application.AddIns("XLAADDIN").Installed = True. before setting the mnuDownload1